# I have 20w castrol and i need a quart of oil but they are out can I add another brand as long as it is the same weight

Tags: oil

hello I have 20w castrol  and i need a quart of oil but they are out can I add another brand as long as it is the same weight

Answer (score 1):

This is opinion-based answer: yes, you may. While the additives may be different, as long as both oils are certified and approved for your particular engine, there will be no "harmful inter-reaction" or any other negative consequences.